# which should i use in request.getParameter in servlet?

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm using HTML5 where I use email as

```
<input type="email" id="txtEmail" name="email" required>
```

in the servlet page if i use `String email=request.getParameter("email");`

instead of

```
String txtEmail=request.getParameter("txtEmail");
```

will it be any problem??will it be error??plz help..

Comment: Why don't you do it & see if there is any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to address the `name` Attribute of your input Elements Serverside. So if you would have `<input type="text" name="username" id="userelementid">` then you would still use `request.getParameter("username")`

Answer (score 0):

[getParameter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)) method looks for the name attribute as your email input has the name `email` so you have to use `request.getParameter("email");`

`txtEmail` is an id so if you use `String txtEmail=request.getParameter("txtEmail");`

then you will get `txtEmail=null`

Comment: then why we use id??thanks in advance..

Comment: @SayamNandy id is useful at client side